# Solving this Fokker-Plack Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I have a bidimensional Fokker-Planck equation to solve, namely,

$$
\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} =  \frac{\sigma_{1}^{2}}{2} \frac{\partial^{2} p}{\partial I^{2}} - \frac{\partial }{\partial S} (b_{1}(S,I) p) - \frac{\partial }{\partial I}(b_{2} (S,I) p) \,\, ,
$$

where,

$$
b_{1} = -aSI \,\, , \\
b_{2} = aSI-\mu I + cI -cSI-cI^2 \,\, .
$$

My initial and Neumann conditions are the following,

$$
p(S,I,0) = \delta (S-S_{0},I-I_{0})  \,\, , \\
\lim_{S,I \to \pm \infty} p(S,I,t)= \lim_{S,I \to \pm \infty} \partial_{S} p(S,I,t) = \partial_{I} p(S,I,t) = 0 \,\, .
$$

How can I solve this FP equation? Can I apply separation of variables?

Comment: Most likely you can't solve it analytically at all, however I think this is in a form where you can get an approximate solution by taking the Kramers-Smolukowski approximation applied to $X=S,V=-aSI$. What I am not sure about is whether the noise contribution to $dV$ will then only depend on $X$ or not, and whether there is a suitable "friction term". (The validity of the approximation will also depend on the parameters, of course.)

Comment: Well, the noise contribution to $dV$ does indeed only depend on $X$, but the drift is of the wrong form due to a term $\frac{V^2}{X}$. This term disappears only in the artificial situation $a=-c$.